Infinite loop while closing another workbook
I'm working on an Excel project where I use VBA and two workbooks :
One to update some tables (analysis requests updated with a macro while opening) and another one where I copy part of those tables adding informations after tables were updated.
The first file where  I have my requests launch an update when it opens :
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Set myCurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook

do some stuffs...

call my_copy

Here is the code in my_copy :
Set myWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(myPath)
myWorkbook.Worksheets(mySheet).Select

do some stuff

myWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

The problem is : seems like Excel crashes when I try to close the second workbook, and relaunched itself. So it relaunchs the first macro, which call my_copy, recrashes, and goes in an infinite loop.
When in my_copy I just let myWorkbook.Save without closing it doesn't crash..
I tried to fix it using two lines like this :
myWorkbook.Save
myWorkbook.Close (True)

But nothing changed..
How could I fix it please ? What's going wrong ?
Best regards

What version of Excel are you using?  In my_copy where do myPath, mySheet come from?  Maybe useful to show more of your code here.

Try this. After everytime you close the workbook, type DoEvents in the next line. Now try it.

When in my_copy I just let myWorkbook.Save without closing it doesn't crash.. I have a feeling and i could be wrong but DoEvents may help yo uout...

'myPath' and 'mySheet' are just variables.. The difference is between save and save and close method that gave me different risults.

@SiddharthRout : doesn't work :( Find a walkaround see beelow :)

Find a walkaround to avoid those problems : In the firstlines of my code, I write on a dedicate cells the current date. Then I add a condition in the initial code :
If myCurrentWorkbook.Worksheets(mySheet).cells(1,1) = Date then Exit Sub

Works because the second time it opens, date were updated and so it stops the loop !!
Thanks everyone for the help.
Jerry
